# convert pandas series to a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

```
Unnamed: 0             0
0_ADNI        233.935909
1_ADNI        171.077273
2_ADNI        240.887273
3_ADNI        272.705909
                 ...
Year                   7
Location              37
```

Is there an easy way to convert pandas series above to a dataframe? I want output like:

```
0_ADNI         1_ADNI        2_ADNI       3_ADNI   .... Year     Location
233.935909     171.077273   240.887273    272.705909      7         37
```

I tried the following, but they do not work

```
series.to_frame()
```

or

```
pd.Dataframe(series)
```

Comment: is `.T` sufficient?

Comment: I think you might be looking for `series.to_frame().T`